# Visual Studio python says else is invalid syntax and is unknown

Tags: python, if-statement

I am writing code in python on the visual studio code IDE with the python extension installed.

There this a part of my code that is :

```
if newuser == "":
    #error 0 code
else:
    return
```

And the **else:** is underlined in red as an error and says

> invalid syntax (, line 153)pylint(syntax-error)

I have other if statements in my code that work but it is just this one

Comment: it's because the body of your `if` is empty.

Comment: Thanks @AliTou Thats fixed it, I was just leaving it for later so I could add it in, so thanks

Comment: Python has a solution for when you need to leave something empty: fill in the `pass` command.  This is Python-ese for "this code block intentionally left blank".

Comment: @Prune That Helps SO much

Comment: I put in an answer that's based on the comments. If it works for you, please accept it to help others (and to give me some of that sweet, sweet rep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an empty statement, Python will throw an error unless you use pass.

```
if newuser == "":
    pass
else:
    return
```

A better way of writing the code is just to use `!=` (meaning 'is not equal to') rather than `==` like below:

```
if newuser != "":
    return
```